# Android ListView alpha in background color only

Tags: android, background, android-listview, alpha-transparency

I have a list view and now all cells have white background.

What I want is to keep the white color in listview's background and put some "**alpha**" value to make it semi transparent so the user can see the whole view's background.

If I put android:alpha in `listview` , everything gets alpha ( the content too ). I want the content of the `listview` to be fully visible and the background color to be **semi-transparent**. Is there any way to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use white color as background, define a color in resources that has a transparency, you could do something like `#66FFFFFF`, this is a transparent white.